# Sending Username/emailid in the saml req as NameID to Keycloak

Tags: authentication, saml, keycloak

We have a requirement to send Username/EmailId in the Subject/NameID field
to the keycloak. Keycloak then receive that value in a custom authenticator
and send it to the tokenvalidator for further flow. The idea here is to
omit the step to ask user name from user again.

1. In Keycloak I am not able to see NameID value since keycloak is not
   putting this in the client session. why?
2. I can see that keycloak is parsing the Subject/Name ID field.  How can I
   get this value in my custom Autheticator ?

Please let me know your suggestions and ideas

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue in the existing keycloak code. created the issue and sent a pull request.

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-3651